# «…было холодное, и полярная шапка…» Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В рассказе Ольги Ларионовой «Развод по-марсиански» есть предложение:

> Он хотел вернуться, но Корели потянула его дальше, ей хотелось обязательно дойти до самого полюса, чтобы увидеть настоящий снег, и они его увидели, потому что лето было холодное и полярная шапка растаяла не до конца.

Цитирую по: Лениздат, 1971.

В 1980 году рассказ опубликовало издательство «Знание», и предложение стало выглядеть так:

> Он хотел вернуться, но Корели потянула его дальше, ей хотелось обязательно дойти до самого полюса, чтобы увидеть настоящий снег, и они его увидели, потому что лето было холодное, и полярная шапка растаяла не до конца.

После слова «холодное» появилась запятая.

Какой же вариант верен?

Заранее благодарен всем ответившим.

Comment: Первый вариант верен: есть общий для двух предложений элемент "потому что" (потому что А и Б). Запятая же разрушает обобщающий смысл. Выходит, что "потому что А, и (независимо от этого, вне "потому что") происходит Б".

Comment: @Alex_ander В данном предложении А и Б связаны причинно-следственной связью (лето было холодное, и [поэтому] полярная шапка не растаяла. Запятая нужна, конечно.

Comment: Странно, но в издательстве "Знание" в 1967 г. запятая [уже была](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=4Kw-AQAAIAAJ&q="лето+было+холодное+и+полярная"&dq="лето+было+холодное+и+полярная"&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju17L-gbrxAhWkxIUKHbdtBM8Q6AF6BAgFEAI). Что уменьшает вероятность авторской ошибки. Вероятно, в Лениздате редактор не смог понять смысл предложения.

Comment: @grizzly Такая смысловая связь есть, и запятая была бы в самостоятельном высказывании из этих двух предложений ("и" заменялось бы на "поэтому"), но с объдинением через грамматически более общее и сильное "потому что" она не уживается: нельзя одними и теми же словами выразить две причинности,  "вложенных" одна в другую. Да, для корректора это сложный случай.

Comment: @Alex_ander Русский язык вполне допускает подобную рекурсию, а союз "и" имеет среди прочих значение причинности — здесь такое употребление необходимо из стилистических соображений. Намного важнее, что признать равноправными А и Б в этом предложении можно только с очень большой скидкой на фантастичность сюжета. Автор, судя по всем остальным изданиям (более ранним и более поздним), такой экзотический смысл в него не вкладывала.

Comment: А и Б здесь не равноправные, причинно зависимые. Несмотря на смысловую (но не грамматическую и это важно) причинно-следственную связь, их можно называть грамматически однородными (добавив и опустив наречие "поэтому" после союза и). Отсюда и зависит постановка запятой. Почему их можно считать однородными, не отрицая причинно-следственной связи? Потому что после "и" можно добавить "поэтому" и заглянуть в Кустову, 2005, где она признает однородными "Этот маяк был более высокий и поэтому более заметный".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая в таких ситуациях ставится не просто так, а выполняет очень-очень отчетливую функцию. Взгляните на один пример:

В газетной заметке указывается, что ожидаются заморозки и следует принять меры к защите ранних овощей от холода. (В газете пишется о заморозках и даются рекомендации.)

В газетной заметке указывается, что ожидаются заморозки, и следует принять меры к защите ранних овощей от холода. (В газете пишется только о заморозках, а рекомендации дает говорящий данное предложение.)

Авторы пунктуации задумывали различать данной запятой последовательные отношения подпредложений и соподчинительные. Путаница возникает в предложениях, где может быть две связи, которые различают смысл, как в предложении выше, или вовсе не различают, а зависят просто от воли пишущего. Например, в таком предложении: «В давно минувшие времена здесь были селения черемисского народа, и жил среди них могучий и славных богатырь Чумбулат» — автор может ставить запятую или не ставить, так как соподчинение или последовательная связь не привнесет никаких смысловых отличий.

В вашем предложении не может быть последовательной связи, поэтому запятая перед «и» не ставится. Оба подпредложения относятся к общему союзу и связаны соподчинительной связью с подпредложением: «и они его увидели».

Comment: Ответ с сайта https://russkiiyazyk.ru/question/bylo-holodnoe-i-polyarnaya-shapka-nuzhna-li-zapyataya#comment-40472: 

Чтобы понять, какой вариант постановки знака препинания является правильным, используем известный прием. Во втором варианте опустим выделенное запятыми придаточное предложение с союзом «потому что» и получим:

…и они его увидели…и полярная шапка растаяла не до конца.

Последнее предложение о полярной шапке никак не связано с предыдущей частью высказывания.

Верен первый вариант, в котором не ставится запятая перед союзом «и», соединяющим однородные придаточные части